# Bad base64 after storing in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, swift, base64

I am developing a simple app for Max OS X for making screenshots using Swift language. After screenshot was made, I convert it into a base64 string using:

```
screenshot.base64EncodedString()
```

I have a simple .php file on my server for saving this base64 string into MySQL database. Everything works well, but when I am trying to receive this image string from server on my android device, it throws an exception while decoding a base64 "bad base64".

This is what I am using to decode image:

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
```

I am using this to put/get image from MySQL database:

Put: `INSERT INTO db (screen) VALUES ('$screen')`
Get: `SELECT * FROM db`

I am storing my base64 as a **LONGTEXT** in my database.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You have specified a lot of platform tags. Please restrict the tags to the one that is relevant to the question.

Comment: When you have e.g. the word "test" what is the base64 encoded string and what does MySQL actually end up storing and what are you ending up retrieving?

Comment: The word "test" is "dGVzdA==" before sending and "dGVzdA==" after receiving. It is stored so in MySQL

Comment: `=` is not a character that would be transferred as it is via an HTTP request so there's a chance you need to do url decoding before base64 decoding

Answer (score 2):

The solution is truly replacing "+" with "-" in base64 encoded string before submitting to MySQL and replacing the "-" with "+" after retrieving from MySQL to get the original string. This is because MySQL replaces "+" with white space. It will solve the problem.

Comment: But this was already suggested. How it got upvoted so quickly while the other not

Comment: Yeah you are right, the previously suggested solution is okay but it wasn't detailed enough, like mentioning that the original base64 string has to be reconstructed by re-replacing the "-" to "+" in the retrieved string.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution! Replacing "+" with "-" in base64 encoded string solved my problem. The problem was that MySQL replaces + whith a space.